# By 5 units less or simply 5 less?

Tags: prepositions, subject-verb-agreement

> In France, 25 units of electricity were produced from gas, and by 5 units
> less were produced with the help of oil.

Should I use 'by' here (I want to say that 20 units of electricity were obtained from oil), and should it be *was* or *were* after '5 units less'?

Comment: Preposition ***by*** is *definitely* unwanted / ungrammatical in your context. Note that idiomatically, few native speakers would repeat the word ***units*** here. So it's just *...and **5 less** were produced with the help of oil.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thanks!

Comment: Note that ***with the help of** oil* is *very* unusual phrasing here. I'm guessing you don't intend some subtly different meaning from *...were produced **from oil*** (matching preceding *...produced **from gas***). But if we knew this text had come from a competent native speaker, we would assume there *must* be some intended difference (I can't guess what, though).

Comment: What FF said, and "unit" is countable, so "*five **fewer***" is preferred.